# Minimize and Restore with Dialogs

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a project using Swing. there is a principal JFrame that calls a secondary JDialog and those secondary dialogs call other jdialog. The secondary dialogs are not modal in the manner i can call more then onde dialog at a time. That way i can call other (3rd level) dialogs for all secondary dialogs open.

When I minimize the principal frame when I have one or more secondary dialogs open and restore it, all windows can be seen correctly but when I have one 3rd level dialog open (remember, its modal to one of the secondary dialog) the other screens cannot be seen unless i close that 3rd level dialog.

I need to minimize the principal frame and restore all windows as they appear before minimize them. How can I do it?

Comment: please for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable, just about `JFrame` with empty `JDialogs` (hardcode setSiz()e for this example),

Comment: You can make a modal dialog from another modal dialog